# How to suppress a certain warning in Spyder editor?

Tags: python, spyder, pyflakes

The editor in Spyder always gives me warnings for unused imports/variables immediately after I type the line. I want to suppress such warnings. How do I do that? 
And I want this to happen for every file I open in the Spyder editor, wouldn't prefer local fixes.

I tried adding 'disable=' in `~/.pylintrc` and it didn't work. Moreover, the Spyder editor uses pyflakes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > Editor > Code Introspection/Analysis`

and deactivate the option called

`Real-time code analysis`

Comment: Is there is no easy way to suppress a specific warning? The OP did say certain warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spyder the linter *pyflakes* is used. You can write a special comment at the end of the line to ignore the line. The following comments work:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa
```

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # analysis:ignore
```

Answer (score -3):

locate preferences -> Editor -> Code Introspection/Analysis -> Deactivate/Uncheck the  Real time code analysis Warning: It will also stop showing errors in the editor

Comment: This is incorrect because it removes warnings when you run your code, not when you're writing it in Spyder's editor.