# How to turn on/off code analysis features in Spyder 4

Tags: anaconda, editor, real-time, spyder, underline

After updating Spyder to 4.0.0, I cannot see any checkbox to turn on or off the "Real-time code analysis"

Here we can see the menu steps that cannot be found anymore:
[How to suppress a certain warning in Spyder editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568959/how-to-suppress-a-certain-warning-in-spyder-editor)
Which contains:
You need to go to
[*Tools > Preferences > Editor > Code Introspection/Analysis*
and deactivate the option called
*Real-time code analysis*]

For versions up to 4.1.3 inclusive, there are the following problems, probably only on Windows:

- I am not able to turn on the warnings that e.g. show which variables are unknown. Normally, if i move code to a separate function, I find out all the needed parameters for the function by just scrolling through the red lines in the code.
- Even the normal code completion does not work. First, nothing is popping up after 3 letters entered after the dot. And then, when Spyder seems to start searching, it is not reacting anymore.

Comment: If code completion and linting are not working for you, that's a bug. Please report it [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) and add a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: I have seen your comment only now. I have added the comments below to a new link https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10993

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Code analysis options in Spyder 4 were significantly expanded and moved to a new entry in our preferences called `Completion and linting`, as shown below:

[image]

To deactivate all linting (which was called before "Real-time code analysis"), you need to turn off the option called `Enable basic linting` in the screenshot above.

**Please update to version 4.1.4 or higher to avoid the mentioned bug on Windows.**

Comment: Now I have used the linting to add the needed passed parameters, but the linting has not disappeared, with error "Undefined Name '....' (pyflakes E), although that variable is a passed parameter to the function in which I use it. I do not know if this is still related to the question, but the linting does at least not work as it had before, I expected any underline to go away as soon as the variable is known in the function. Probably I have to change something in the pyflakes setup to refresh automatically? Thank you.

Comment: I have set linting - "Enable basic linting" and "Underline errors and warnings" of and on again, all of the red lines are gone, also where they still should be, and red x circles on the left show the same "undefined name …" error at positions where the parameter is definitely already known.

Comment: The problems have not disappeared, though I had a working linting for a while. Spyder has crashed 3 times today, linting worked only sometimes, and now linting is there, but without refreshing, that means not disappearing when I have already added the missing parameter.

Comment: I get false warnings every time I rename a variable. It flags me that "old variable name" is assigned to but never use. Coupled with all the crashes I get everyday, I honestly don't know what I'm waiting for to switch to a different IDE...

Comment: Linting and code completion are still not working for me. I raised an issue on the Spyder Github site and was told it would be fixed in 4.1.2. I have now upgraded and even done a "factory reset" but no luck. In the status bar it says "LSP Python: Ready" which I believe means the linting engine is running, and I have all settings for linting and code completion turned on, but nothing happens.

Comment: In version 4.1.4, linting still does not work, code completion does. See the new screenshots.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You need to give us a way to reproduce those errors though. Otherwise, we won't be able to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

***The problems have been fixed by Spyder version 4.1.4***, please just update your Spyder. Use the update steps on https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases.

ccordoba12 on GitHub has the good news, see again: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10993#issuecomment-647616536

> We had a long time trying to figure out why code completion and
> linting were failing. However, I think we finally nailed the issue: it
> was a problem that only appeared on Windows and @OverLordGoldDragon
> was critical in providing us a reproducible use case with which I
> could finally fix it. The fix will be available in our next version
> (4.1.4), to be released by the end of this week or early during the
> next one.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround for versions 4.0.0 till 4.1.3**

result of github help: start spyder in **debug** mode with

```
spyder --debug-info verbose --debug-output file
```

see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/10993#issuecomment-563414784

The debug mode gives back all the code analysis features. You can probably drop the `--debug-output file` (untested). For versions 4.0.0 till 4.1.4 you need to start Spyder always like this, else the missing linting returns (at least on Windows). **This bug was fixed with Spyder 4.1.4.**